# How to get sum of column by using condition in query MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like the following:

| VALUE | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | DEBET |
| 50 | DEBET |
| 10 | DEBET |
| 20 | DEBET |
| 30 | KREDIT |
| 80 | KREDIT |

I want to get the result as follows:

| DEBET (SUM OF DEBET STATUS) | KREDIT (SUM OF KREDIT STATUS) |
| --- | --- |
| 180 | 110 |

How should I do it in a sum query MySQL?

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'group value' THEN value ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: @Akina this is the answer, put it as answer

Comment: @Asyah check the solution below

Comment: Thanks @Akina this is what I need. Please put it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'DEBET'  THEN value ELSE 0 END) as 'SUM OF DEBET STATUS',
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'KREDIT' THEN value ELSE 0 END) as 'SUM OF KREDIT STATUS'
FROM tableName
;
```

In this query we have conditional `SUM` for `DEBET/KREDIT` which will sum up values for rows with appropriate status.

Comment: you didn't add group by, the code will not run

Comment: Actually group by not needed here, because result must be only 1 row with appropriate sums.

Comment: yes unless he adds status in the select as well, you are right

Comment: Thanks @cn007b , this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(STATUS='DEBET', VALUE , 0)) 'DEBET', 
    SUM(IF(STATUS='KREDIT', VALUE , 0)) 'KREDIT'
FROM
    <table_name>
```

if condition matches, then only adds the value else adds 0.

Answer (score -1):

USE case when statements to filter the sum based on your requirements

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'DEBIT' THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_DEBIT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'KREDIT' THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_KREDIT
    FROM
    [TABLE NAME]
```

if you want the output as per status then you can use this code:

```
    SELECT 
        STATUS,
        SUM(VALUE) AS TOTAL_VALUE
        FROM
        [TABLE NAME]

GROUP BY 1
```